# Check if any pending/running promises exist anywhere in your entire Node.js process (without having access to promise variables themselves)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

Is there some way in Node.js to get an answer to this question?

- Does this Node process/program currently have ANY pending/running promises?
- ...globally/anywhere in any scope
- ...and without having any promise variables "on hand" to check manually

...or better yet, get a count of the number of pending promises anywhere across the whole process.

If this has been discussed before, then I have no idea if anything has changed since then.  Node.js constantly evolves and adds features.

Comment: I don't think so. But you can create a code that will do this. Try to play with monkey patching the Promise object, maybe using some Proxy.